# Distinguish a letter input from an integer input in c

Tags: c

There are two kinds of input that can be provided:

```
50
b 2 40
```

I have to distinguish both the cases and then take further actions accordingly. Here's what I have tried:

```
char input[100];
fgets(input, 100, stdin);
printf("%s", input);
int count = 0;
char a[3][100];
int j=0, i=0;
while(true){

  a[count][j] = input[i];
  j++; i++;

  if(input[i] == '\n'){
    break;
  }
  if(input[i] == ' '){
    count++;
    j = 0;
    i++;
  }
}
printf("%d\n", count);
printf("%s\n", a[0]);
printf("%s\n", a[1]);
printf("%s\n", a[2]);
```

For example, input:

```
b 6767 9090
```

output:

```
b 6767 9090
b 6767 9090
2
b����
67670
9090
```

Can somebody help me on how to do this? I was suggested previously to use fgets. As I am a beginner in C, I am having difficulty figuring out how to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478932/check-if-user-inputs-a-letter-or-number-in-c

Comment: You aren't adding a null terminator at `a[count][j]` when you hit a space or carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

You should either set a `'\0'` or null terminator when a space is encountered, or you can previously set all the element of the array with 0 or null like this -

`char a[3][100] = {0};`

Answer (score 1):

Also, this program will crash if user inputs string which has more than three words (i.e.., count > 2) since loop while(true) tries until it hits \n character.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the best way to do this would be:

```
char inp[25];
scanf("%s", inp);
if(inp[0] == 'b'){
  int r, v;
  scanf("%d %d", &r, &v);
}
else{
  int v = atoi(inp);
}
```